# Value null is converted into "" with React on input types

Tags: javascript, reactjs

on my application I have some fields that the user needs to fill.When the field is empty, it shows the value null.When I enter something on the input field, it assumes that same value with no problem.

My problem is when I have an input field that has information.When I delete the value on it this is what it shows:

[image]

As you can see the value is null indeed.This is done by on this method with this lines of code:

```
handleChange(event, index) {

    if (event.target.value == '') {
        event.target.value = null;
    }

       (...)
   }
```

However,when sending this name to my API, this same name appears not as null but as "",as you can see:

[image]

This is how Im printing this value:

```
            window.alert("test->-> " +JSON.stringify(jsonPlayer.playerName))
```

The concnlusion that I take from this is that the JSON.stringify is transforming my null value to "", and I want the value to be null and not "".
When sending to my API this happens too because I need to stringify my object too:

```
 return fetch(url, {

        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            player: param

        })
```

Is there any way to transform the "" that stringify puts to null without sequential if clauses?

Thanks.

UPDATE WITH MORE CODE:

initial State:

```
this.state = {
        playerList: {
            player: [
                {
                    idPlayer: null,
                    playerName: null,
                    broadcastChannel: null,
                    clusterName: null,
                    playerAlias: [
                        {
                            name: null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        newAlias: null
    }
```

Full Handle change method:

```
handleChangeFirstChild(event, index) {

    if (event.target.value === "") {
        this.state.playerList.player[index].playerName=null;
    }

    const player = [...this.state.playerList.player]

    player[index] = {
        ...player[index],
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }

    window.alert("player's name no JSON.stringify: " + player[index].playerName)
    window.alert("player's name with JSON.stringify: " + JSON.stringify(player[index].playerName))

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        playerList: {
            ...prevState.playerList,
            player: [
                ...player,
            ]
        }
    }))
}
```

first print:

[image]

second print:

[image]

What the api receives, just for clarification:

[image]

Comment: JSON.stringify is transforming my null value to "". This is wrong. It does not transform null into "". Yare are not updating state in react component. The state value seems to be at "" . Hence "" is going in your fetch call. Can you provide more code for better help

Comment: Any `input` element's `value` property will **always** contain a `String`. If you assign `null` or `true`or `false` it will hold `"null"`, `"true"`, or `"false"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding `event.target.value = null`:

```js
    if (event.target.value === '') {
        this.setState({...jsonPlayer,playerName: null})
        // if no render needed:
        // jsonPlayer.playerName = null;
        return;
    }
...
```

In this case:

```js
JSON.stringify(jsonPlayer.playerName) // 'null'
```